# Print button greyed out on GeoExplorer?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, printing, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I have recently downloaded and installed the OpenGeo Suite from Boundless, and I am running through a few tutorials. I'm using GeoExplorer to manipulate layers defined in GeoServer (running from my localhost) which is in turn connected to a PostGIS db (again stored locally).

I am successfully logged on as the admin and I have successfully published my map in GeoExplorer to a html page.

I want to now export it to a pdf, but my print button is greyed out.

Does anyone know why the print button is greyed out?

Comment: I have followed the instructions but still the print option is not working. What is this config.yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGeo Suite does not come with the GeoServer print extension. You'll need to download that community extension and manually install it in GeoServer. GeoExplorer will then enable the print button. Make sure you use the correct version based on the GeoServer version used, e.g.: http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.4.x/community-latest/

Comment: Perfect, thank you. For other newbies reading this, installation instructions on the print module can be found [here:](http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.5.x/doc/en/user/community/printing/index.html)

Comment: It didn't work here. I followed exactly the steps but the button is still not working.
Geoserver 2.6.1 with OpenGeo Suite 4.5